# (Tutorial) Script does not run due SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js

As per Quill's suggestion, I am posting this again. The first time I posted "npm update node" fixed the problem.

I bought a tutorial from Packtpub.com called "Web Development with NodeJs and MongoDB" and I want to run the sample tutorial code. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('Argument vector');
console.log(process.argv);

let args = process.argv.slice(2);

console.log('\nArguments after slicing');
console.log(args);    
let name = args[0];    
if (!name) {
    throw Error('\nYou have not given your name, bye');
}

console.log('\nHello ' + name);
```

So I download and install Node-v5.6.0-x64.msi. Why do I get errors when I use the let command:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "c:/Users/v-sihein/Documents/books/2016/javascript/Web Development with Node.JS and MongoDB/3413OS_Section 01_Code/1/1.3/" -*-
Compilation started at Sat Feb 13 16:25:01

node 03-hello-arguments.js siegfried
c:\Users\v-sihein\Documents\books\2016\javascript\Web Development with Node.JS and MongoDB\3413OS_Section 01_Code\1\1.3\03-hello-arguments.js:9
let args = process.argv.slice(2);
^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sat Feb 13 16:25:01
```

Now if I change the "let"s to "var"s then it works!

I had this problem previously (a couple of days ago) and "npm update node" fixed the problem (I think -- maybe I mistakenly ran the version with the "var" instead of the "let"). However, I have since reinstalled windows 10 and now "npm update node" does not fix the problem any more.

So what versions of javascript and ecmascript can I expect to be able to execute with node v5.6.0? I've been boogle searching and I cannot find a simple table of javascript features for the different versions of node and javascript. I would think knowing what versions of javascript/ecmascript is supported by a version node would be very basic/important information to every node programmer! Can someone point me to such a table?

Did I buy a bad tutorial? I think the author uses linux or MAC and I'm using windows. Should not node work the same way on mac/linux and windows?

Please tell me if this program works for you on your computer. Be sure to mention if you are running mac, unix, linux or windows (or something else?).

Thanks 
Siegfried

Comment: either `"use strict"` in your code, or use the `--harmony_sloppy_let` command line switch, or the `--use_strict` command line switch

Comment: You need to verify what version of node.js you're actually running.   `node -v` will tell you.

Comment: The title is not very descriptive. As for which language features Node supports, see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add `'use strict'` to the beginning of the js part

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict'
(...)
```

This will then immediately work. It's weird that the tutorial doesn't mention that.

Comment: Thanks -- 'use strict' and --use-strict do the job.

Comment: Ohhh -- I had to google search to learn how to do that because I did not know I could mark it as answered. OK! Good to know about that green check mark. Thank you everyone1